# Automate the command curl to download multiple URLs

Tags: ubuntu, curl

How can I run `curl` on multiple URLs example:

```
curl https://google.com/1 
curl https://google.com/2 
curl https://google.com/3
```

I would like to automate `curl` every 60 seconds.

Comment: Hello @Martynas. Would you please clarify whether you would like to download all the URLs, and after 60 re-downloading all the URLs again, OR you would like to wait 60 seconds between each URL. Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below,

1) Create file MultiCurl.sh

```
/usr/bin/curl "https://google.com/1"
/usr/bin/curl "https://google.com/2"
/usr/bin/curl "https://google.com/3"
```

2) Make it executable with chmod

```
chmod +x MultiCurl.sh
```

3) Added it in Cron Job

```
*/60 * * * * $Scriptpath/MultiCurl.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the command `wget`  with the flag `--i`. Put all the urls in a file list.txt, then run `wget`

```
cat list.txt
https://google.com/1 
https://google.com/2 
https://google.com/3 


wget --i ./list.txt
```